# AngularJS/Json without ng-repeat, how to show the data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

For some reason, I have to use ng-repeat in order to display data. I'd like to display data without using ng-repeat.

angular:

```
App.controller('aboutLongCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('test_data/ar_org.json')
    .then(function (res) {
        $scope.aboutlongs = res.data.aboutlong;
    });
});
```

Here's my markup:

```
<div class="background-white p20 reasons" ng-controller="aboutLongCtrl" >
    <h6 ng-repeat="aboutlong in aboutlongs"><b>About {{aboutlong.name}}</b></h6>
    <div class="reason-content" ng-repeat="aboutlong in aboutlongs">
       {{aboutlong.description}}
    </div>
</div>
```

If I use this, it won't work.. can anyone explain why?

```
<div class="background-white p20 reasons" ng-controller="aboutLongCtrl" >
    <h6><b>About {{aboutlong.name}}</b></h6>
    <div class="reason-content">
       {{aboutlong.description}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I followed this approach but it won't work:
[How to Display single object data with out Using ng-repeat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35779786/how-to-display-single-object-data-with-out-using-ng-repeat)

I'm guessing it's because of my angular code, something isn't right.

Comment: without ng-repeat how to show the data's

Comment: Without ng-repeat u can do but create your own directive like ng-repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably variable **`aboutlongs`**  is an array of Objects.

In first case ng-repeat directive repeats a set of HTML, a given number of times.

If you still want to access the Object you can access the array Index and display it.

```
<div class="background-white p20 reasons" ng-controller="aboutLongCtrl" >
        <h6><b>About {{aboutlongs[0].name}}</b></h6>
           <div class="reason-content">
           {{aboutlongs[0].description}}
          </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: check above sample

Comment: I tried that but it won't work.. `{{aboutlong[0].name}}`

Comment: hi @Sajeetharan could you help 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43315615/how-to-upload-the-image-in-public-folder-and-retrieve-it-in-angularjs-mean-stack

Answer (score 1):

`ng-repeat` is used to print an array

```
<div class="reason-content" ng-repeat="aboutlong in aboutlongs">
   {{aboutlong.description}}
 </div>
```

Here `abvoutlongs` is array and you are extracting single element in every repeat `aboutlong`..

`<div class="reason-content">
     {{aboutlongs[0].description}}
     {{aboutlongs[1].description}}
</div>`

this will also work .. as we are accessing element of array `aboutlongs` one by one

Answer (score 1):

probably, the res.data.aboutlong is assigning an array to $scope.aboutlongs. And an array can only be displayed using ng-repeat.
Alternatively, you may also use

```
<h6><b>About {{aboutlong[0].name}}</b></h6>
```

to **avoid** ng-repeat. However, I strongly suggest you to stick with ng-repeat.

Comment: Can you explain why I should stuck with ng-repeat when I don't need it?

Comment: Since that is an array that you are assigning to the variable and the very purpose of array is to display a list of similar repetitive objects. So, I suggested you to stick with the ng-repeat. It will help you handle when there is only one or a hundred objects coming in the array.

Suppose, as of now, you are receiving two objects in the array and imagine that if you are using it as :  {{aboutlong[0].name}} and {{aboutlong[1].name}} and going further you started to receive third object in the array, then you will have to come back and make changes in the code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but in this control I won't need any repetition ever. I guess I shouldn't use the array to begin with. Thanks!